# Android App, reading textfile from res

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have looked through tons different solutions to this problem, but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to make an app that reads in a text file and displays parts of it on the screen. I'm having a problem reading the file though, and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I've been debugging the code, and it throws a IO java exception (fileNotFound).. It does not execute the file-reading parts of the code.. I never reach the while loop.. It throws the exception before I reach it.

I put the file in the `/res/raw directory`

The error output in the LogCat is: `threadid=3 Thread exiting due to uncaught exception`

When I compile the code it also complains about a nullPointerException on line 48 which I do not understand since I don't seem to reach that part of the code in the debugger.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class AndroidReadTest extends Activity {

HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> table = new HashMap();

Random rand = new Random();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String category = "";
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList();


    try {
/**         AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("AndroidReadTest/res/raw/questions");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor())); */

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.questions))); // I have tried adding .txt

        while(in.readLine()!=null){

            ......

        }
        table.put(category, temp);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(click);    
}

public String get(ArrayList<String> questions){

    int temp = questions.size();        
    String str = questions.get(rand.nextInt(temp));
    return str;
}

private OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View V){
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.append(get(table.get("---Cathegory")));    
    }
};


}
```

Comment: Using assets might be the better way to go, but I think this should work too. Which line is line 48? If it's the `BufferedReader in = ...` line, then break that line into different variables (one for the `Resources`, one for the `InputStream`, etc. Then run it again and it should tell you which part is breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your text file in the assets folder of your project instead of res/raw.

[This page has a nice overview](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/assets.html) of how to store the files.

[AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) is how you access them from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.filename);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```